# Haskell in Excel

Tags: haskell

I've seen a couple of sources casually refer to the idea of *"Haskell in an Excel spreadsheet"* - as if this is something that everybody is familiar with and knows about.

This is certainly news to me. The *idea* has obvious appeal - Haskell would be ideally suited to this kind of thing. But has anybody ever actually got this to work?

Comment: A few banks have got this to work.

Comment: @DonStewart I was just listening to your great [HaskellCast](http://www.haskellcast.com/episode/002-don-stewart-on-real-world-haskell/) where it very much sounded like this is something you have up and running at your work. Is there any chance for ordinary folk to get at it too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This paper by David Wakeling discusses combining a standard spreadsheet application (Excel) with a standard functional language (Haskell): http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1194878

From the abstract:

> The functional programming community has shown some interest in
>   spreadsheets, but surprisingly no one seems to have considered making
>   a standard spreadsheet, such as Excel, work with a standard functional
>   programming language, such as Haskell. In this paper, we show one way
>   that this can be done. Our hope is that by doing so, we might get
>   spreadsheet programmers to give functional programming a try.

Comment: SPJ also did some work on Excel, although I don't know if it was added to the language: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/excel/

Answer (score 2):

It's usually referred to as "Haskell **as** an excel spreadsheet" -- a metaphor for how functional declarative languages work: defining data relationships, instead of processes.

(e.g. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction#What_is_functional_programming.3F)

Comment: Good point. I often tell people that "what SQL does for data storage, Haskell does for _everything_". The spreadsheet metaphor is also obviously applicable.